# Selecting only non-NULL keys in a Postgres JSONB field

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgres-9.6

I have a postgres 9.6 table with a JSONB column

```
> SELECT id, data FROM my_table ORDER BY id LIMIT 4;

 id |               data    
----+---------------------------------------
  1 | {"a": [1, 7], "b": null, "c": [8]}
  2 | {"a": [2, 9], "b": [1], "c": null}
  3 | {"a": [8, 9], "b": null, "c": [3, 4]}
  4 | {}
```

As you can see, some JSON keys have `null` values.

I'd like to exclude these - is there an easy way to `SELECT` only the non-`null` key-value pairs to produce:

```
 id |               data    
----+---------------------------------------
  1 | {"a": [1, 7], "c": [8]}
  2 | {"a": [2, 9], "b": [1]}
  3 | {"a": [8, 9], "c": [3, 4]}
  4 | {}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the code you wrote that didn't produce your desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_strip_nulls()`

```
select id, jsonb_strip_nulls(data) as data
from my_table;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/GGJRW83576

Note that this function would not remove `null` values inside the arrays.